# Reemplazar los valores dentro una columna de DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tablas

estoy comenzando en la programación con Python y en el mundo de análisis de datos, en este momento estoy con un pequeño proyecto, pero estoy un poco atascado, ya que no se como reemplazar los valores de una columna de un dataframe condicionalmente.

Por ejemplo:

En esta tabla tengo 2 columnas una de la medida y otra de la unidad en la que se midio.

Mi idea es convertir todas las "pulgada" en 2,5 y todos los "centímetro" en 1, para así multiplicar la longitud por la "unidad de medida" que ahora son 1 y 2.5, para obtener todas las medidas en cm y poder trabajar en una sola unidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi idea fue convertir la columna "unidad de medida" en una lista y luego con un bucle reemplazar los valores, pero algo debo haber hecho mal porque no me funciona.

```
moneda_list = data["moneda"].values.tolist()

for i in moneda_list:
    if i == "UF":
        i= 30000
```

nota: La tabla que mostré anteriormente la hice solo como ejemplo, las tabla original que es la que corresponde con el código que les muestro es muy distinta

Pero al imprimir posteriormente "moneda_list" me sigue saliendo la lista original sin reemplazar ningún valor.

Les agradezco de antemano si me ayudan a ver mi error o si conocen otra manera mas facil de obtener el resultado que busco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas es una librería especializada en manejo de datos tabulares. Como tal tiene ya definidas cantidad de funciones para hacer tareas comunes que *aparentemente* actúan sobre todos los elementos de una columna a la vez, sin necesidad de iterar por ellos.

Este tipo de operaciones se denominan *vectorizadas* y naturalmente hay un bucle en alguna parte que recorre los elementos, pero la clave es que ese bucle no lo escribes tú, sino que forma parte del corazón de Pandas y la mayoría de las veces se trata de código altamente optimizado y escrito en C.

En definitiva, siempre que puedas evitarlo **no debes iterar** sobre los elementos de un dataframe, ni convertirlo en lista para operar sobre la lista, sino **usar los métodos pandas** que te dan esa funcionalidad.

Para lo que buscas, el método es `.replace()` un nombre bastante intuitivo y cuya documentación puedes consultar [aqui](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html). Tiene varias formas diferentes de uso, y en tu caso particular la más conveniente sería pasarle un diccionario cuyas claves sean los datos que quieres sustituir y cuyos valores sea el resultado de la sustitución.

Es decir, sobre los datos de ejemplo que proporcionas bastaría algo como:

```
df["unidad de medida"] = df["unidad de medida"].replace(
       { "centimetro": 1, "pulgada": 2.5 })
```

O en tu caso real:

```
data["moneda"] = data["moneda"].replace(
       { "UF": 30000,   # etc...
       })
```

Answer (score 0):

Me gusta  utilizar where para estos casos:

```
import numpy as np

df['nueva_col']=np.where(df['unidad de medida']=='centimetros',1,
                np.where(df['unidad de medida']=='pulgadas',2.5,0))
```

Saludos

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).